# Setting up authentication with Devise into a wiki

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just setup a basic rails wiki app. Where user comes in and creates a wiki. And i also just setup devise. Now i am wondering how do i show only those wikis creating by the specific logged in user ?

Update : I have setup the wiki. using scaffold. And have setup the devise authentication. And i just wondering should i be setting up an association between the wiki model and the user model ?
or how should i proceed with the problem mentioned ?

Thanks

Comment: updated the question, i am basically looking to show only the wiki created a specific user and i am not sure how to proceed with taht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise provides a convenience method called `current_user` that retrieves the currently logged in user.

Assuming you have your models setup correctly, retrieving the wikis created by a user should be as easy as `current_user.wikis`

Comment: well i am not sure about model setup, thats what i want to i guess,..because current_user is not stored in the database, so that means it will show all the wikis no matter what the user is